# How can this condition be put in template partial specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, partial-specialization

```
template<size_t bits_count, typename = void>
struct best_type {
};

template<size_t bits_count>
struct best_type<bits_count,enable_if_t<bits_count > 8>> { // error: template argument 2 is invalid
  typedef byte type;
};
```

The error is because of the parser sees the second template argument as `enable_if_t<bits_count >` following a random `8`.

Obviously the solution to this can be replacing the argument of `enable_if_t` to `bits_count >= 9`, but can something be done to preserve the original expression so it will make sense to future readers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add additional parentheses to explain the compiler what you mean:

```
template<size_t bits_count>
struct best_type<bits_count,enable_if_t<(bits_count > 8)>> {
    typedef byte type;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the condition in parentheses.

```
template<size_t bits_count, typename = std::enable_if_t<true>>
struct best_type {
};

template<size_t bits_count>
struct best_type<bits_count, std::enable_if_t<(bits_count > 8)>> {
    using type = byte;
};
```

Also note that I have replaced the `void` with `std::enable_if_t<true>`, since it makes more sense to the reader.

Also note that it is better to use `using` aliases (as compared to `typedef`s) in C++

Comment: `void` is clear. Naming the parameter `Enabler` or `AlwaysVoid` would make the pattern clearer.